# Double to string conversion error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was trying to convert variable of a double datatype to string and vice versa, but I encountered the errors generated by logcat. Please help me to find and correct the mistake.

JavaCode:

```
public class DataTypeConversion extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView stringValue;
TextView numericValue;
double var;
String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_type_conversion);

    stringValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stringValue);
    numericValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numericValue);

    stringValue.setText("0123.45");
    var = Double.valueOf((String) stringValue.getText());
    text = String.valueOf(var);
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.datatypeconversion.DataTypeConversion$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/stringValue"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/numericValue"/>
```

LOGCAT output:

```
04-16 09:17:20.715: D/AndroidRuntime(1056): Shutting down VM
04-16 09:17:20.715: W/dalvikvm(1056): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.datatypeconversion/com.example.datatypeconversion.DataTypeConversion}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.example.datatypeconversion.DataTypeConversion.onCreate(DataTypeConversion.java:31)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-16 09:17:20.735: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     ... 11 more
04-16 09:17:24.825: I/Process(1056): Sending signal. PID: 1056 SIG: 9
```

Comment: On which line you are getting `NPE`?

Comment: @Spring: what is NPE?

Comment: @user3533250: `NPE` is the short form of `NullPointerException`.

Comment: What's on line 31? I am guessing 'stringValue.setText("0123.45");' and  therefore it failed to find the TextView with id R.id.stringValue.

Comment: @user3533250: No. your error is not related to double to string conversion. It is a NullPointerException, and you know exactly where it happens. Now go to the line where it is thrown, and figure out what is null./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is crashing on this line:

```
stringValue.setText("0123.45");
```

That means that this line returned null:

```
 stringValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stringValue);
```

The most likely culprit of this is that you don't have a TextView with the id stringValue in `activity_data_type_conversion.xml`, which is your layout. Make sure that the text view exists there, and has the right ID value, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, i hope it helps you

```
var = Double.valueOf(stringValue.getText().toString());
```

Comment: you do realize a/ this answer was already given b/ the string cast is useless?

Comment: Doesn't `toString()` always return a string?

Comment: I think yes, because getText return char sequence and we must to convert it to String

Comment: @KostyaKhuta: `getText()` returns a `CharSequence`. That does not mean it is a String. `toString()`, however, explicitely returns a String. Always. That's what the method declaration says. There is no need to cast it.